# SELECT Input only returns limited values from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This might sound odd but hopefully someone could figure out and help me with this.

I am retrieving a number of values from the MySql database. I have at least 300 rows in my database which is being exported to my JavaScript file. These values are presented as `<option>` in my `<select>` input. When I run my file, the `<select>` input did not return any `<option>` value.

I wonder what was going on and realize that there are a lot of values returned. So I put a limit on the SQL data and I concluded that the `<select>` input only returns a maximum of 13 values if there is no `WHERE`function in the php code and only 10 values if there is a `WHERE` function.

I did tried putting the data manually without retrieving data from database and it only accepts 25 values out of at least 300 values.

My questions are:

- Are there really limits on the data displayed in the `<select>`
  input? If there is, is there any way to bypass it? If none, what
  could have went wrong?

These are the codes in case you need it. I just simplified and remove few data to visualize what I mean.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Search Topic
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <select id="userDropdown" name="tid" class="select2_single form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></select>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Description <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="description" name="description"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Assigned to <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="assign" name="assign" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Comments: <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments"   class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Words</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input id="words" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="words">
    </div>
</div>


  </div>
<div class="ln_solid"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 <script>



    //sql data...
    var data = [   <?php
        $req = mysql_query('select * from tasks');
            while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
              {
              ?>  {username: '<?php echo $dnn['username'] ?>', tid: '<?php echo $dnn['tid'] ?>', description: '<?php echo $dnn['description'] ?>'},
    //this would return at least 300 results

<?php } ?>

    ];

    var dropdown = $('#userDropdown');
    dropdown.append('<option value="" >Search for Topic ID</option>');
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var item = data[i];
        dropdown.append('<option value="' + item.tid + '" >' + item.tid + '-' + item.description + '</option>');
    }

    $('#userDropdown').change(function(){
        var user = this.value;
        var dataItem = $.grep(data, function(e){ return e.tid == user; });

        if(dataItem.length > 0){
            $('#description').val(dataItem[0].description);
            $('#assign').val(dataItem[0].assign);
            }
    });
    </script>
```

There is no problem with the code. I just included it for reference.

**EDIT:** Remove LIMIT on the php script to avoid confusion.

Comment: Its on purpose, because if I will set limit higher than 13 or no limit at all, it would not display anything.

Comment: Things will go wrong when your data has single quotes, double quotes, less-than signs... so yes, there is  a problem with your code.

Comment: which part? the data from database is echoed as it should. the only problem is that the select input only returns up to 13 options only out of 300.

Comment: it does only work if there are only a maximum of 30 data, else it would not display anything.

Comment: Also don't use *mysql_* functions, they have been deprecated for a long time now, and are no longer supported in PHP 7.

Comment: Open your javacsript console: any errors (when you fetch 300 records)? I predict there are.

Comment: inspect the generated HTML from the browser and check if the options are there but formatted wrong

Comment: How does it affect the number of values returned by select input?

Comment: @Gus the format might be wrong since I already simplify it.

Comment: you will need to make your php code limiting to 30 and querying in loop by decreasing the start row

Comment: *"How does it affect the number of values returned by select input?"*: if there is a javascript syntax error because you did not correctly escape characters, the SELECT will not be populated, eventhough PHP sent the data.

Comment: @trincot there is. Unexpected identifier on line 248. And the line 248 is the var data.

Comment: And that explains the behaviour. Conclusion: always check for errors in console. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the `<select>` element. a more elegant way to do this job is to use the **[here-doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** syntax in **php** like this :

```
var data = [
    <?php
        $req = mysql_query('select * from tasks');
        while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            echo <<<DATA
            {
                username : '{$dnn['username']}',
                tid : {$dnn['tid']},
                description : '{$dnn['description']}'
            }           
DATA;
        }
    ?>
];
```

also keep in mind that :

> this javascript-php snippet should be embedded in the view parsed by
>   php engine

you should not put it in an external asset that would load after parsing the view by **php** & loaded via browser.

Comment: I think I could go from here.

Comment: Great! This actually works. It make me see what the real problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could perhaps do it a little differently like this:

```
<?php
    $data=array();
    $req = mysql_query('select * from tasks');

    if( $req ){
        while( $dnn = mysql_fetch_object( $req ) ){
            $data[]=array( 'username'=>$dnn->username, 'tid'=>$dnn->tid, 'description'=>$dnn->description );
        }

        echo "var data=".json_encode( $data ).";";

    }
?>
```

Alternative, using `mysql_fetch_array`:

```
<?php
    $data=array();
    $req = mysql_query('select * from tasks');

    if( $req ){
        while( $dnn = mysql_fetch_array( $req ) ){
            $data[]=array( 'username'=>$dnn['username'], 'tid'=>$dnn['tid'], 'description'=>$dnn['description'] );
        }

        echo "var data=".json_encode( $data ).";";

    }
?>
```

This is a fully tested, working example including the actual db details

```
$dbhost =   'localhost';
$dbuser =   'root'; 
$dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
$dbname =   'xxx';

/*
create table if not exists `tasks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  `tid` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `description` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=4 default charset=latin1;

insert into `tasks` (`id`, `username`, `tid`, `description`) values
    (1, 'fred', 1, 'banana'),
    (2, 'joe', 2, 'apple'),
    (3, 'bertrum', 3, 'orange');
*/

$conn=mysql_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd );
mysql_select_db( $dbname, $conn ) or die(mysql_error());

$sql='select * from tasks';
$res=mysql_query( $sql );

if( $res ){
    $data=array();
    while( $dnn=mysql_fetch_object( $res ) ){
        $data[]=array( 'username'=>$dnn->username, 'tid'=>$dnn->tid, 'description'=>$dnn->description );    
    }
    echo "var data=".json_encode( $data ).";";
}
mysql_close( $conn );
```

### output:

```
var data=[{"username":"fred","tid":"1","description":"banana"},{"username":"joe","tid":"2","description":"apple"},{"username":"bertrum","tid":"3","description":"orange"}];
```

Comment: This looks like PDO.

Comment: nope - standard, and now deprecated, mysql_query as in your original. I just prefer the object notation to array notation when accessing record sfrom the recordset which is why I used `mysql_fetch_object`

Comment: I get rid of the Unexpected Identifier error but the query does not return any data.

Comment: @crozland23, how did you determine that the query does not return any data? Be careful to make the right diagnosis: it could be that the query does return data (and I think it does), but that for some reason it is not displayed in the SELECT list. That is a different thing.

Comment: it does not RETURN any data when I inspect element. Thus, it also does not displayed in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

There are these potential problems:

1. The data produced by PHP to fill up the *data* Javascript array may contain single quotes, thereby breaking the Javascript code, which will then not proceed to fill the `SELECT`;
2. The data may also contain double quotes, which will break the Javascript code that populates the `SELECT` list;
3. Any less-than or greater-than signs in the data could make the HTML not render correctly;
4. There could be a character encoding problem, so that non-UTF-8 characters are interpreted as such and give unexpected results.

To solve these issues, you should produce JSON and populate the `SELECT` list via DOM methods (via jQuery's *val()* and *text()*), not via string concatenation.

Here is code you could try with:

PHP:

```php
<?php
// right after connecting to the DB:
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
// ...
$req = mysql_query('select * from tasks');
$rows = array();
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) {
    $rows[] = $dnn;
}
?>
```

Followed by this Javascript:

```
var data = <?=json_encode($rows)?>;
var dropdown = $('#userDropdown');
dropdown.append('<option value="" >Search for Topic ID</option>');
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var item = data[i];
    dropdown.append(
        $("<option></option>").val(item.id).text(
            item.tid + '-' + item.description));
}

$('#userDropdown').change(function(){
//  ... etc...
```

For UTF-8 related problems, also make sure your PHP file is saved in UTF-8 encoding. Editors often have an option for this. Secondly, make sure your HTML `head` section specifies a character set. For instance, like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
```

Note that mysql_ functions have been deprecated for a long time now, and are not supported any more in PHP 7. You should switch to mysqli or PDO.

Note also that your HTML has a closing `</DIV>` too many, just above:

```
<div class="ln_solid"></div>
```

Comment: I think you have missed a $ in rows = array(); but anyway. can you also help me retrieve the data values so it would follow the format {username='username value', tid ='tid'}?

Comment: Corrected that. Now check the source of your web page (view source) and read the javascript line that starts with `var data = `. What does it say?

Comment: This: <script>


//sql data...
var data = ;

var dropdown = $('#userDropdown');

Comment: I think you are suffering from a character encoding problem. Please provide the code you connect with. You should add `charset=utf8` in the connection string. `json_encode` seems to crash on a bad character.

Comment: can you give me an idea where to put `charset=utf8` ?

Comment: I put it in my answer. There is a function for it.

Comment: OK, but also note `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`

Comment: I got it now with the help of @Ramin. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, although I am a bit surprised that with Ramin's solution it works, as here-doc it is just a different syntax to do exactly the same as you already did. Namely, it does not solve potential problems with quotes, double quotes, less-than, etc. From our discussion I am quite sure you had a UTF-8 problem, which you somehow solved, but using here-doc has nothing to do with that.

Comment: It was actually the entries in my database causing it. For instance, with Ramin's solution, the results appeared in each line which help me determine which line is exactly causing the issue. And I found out that some of the entries in my database has a quote which causes the issue. My code actually should work, I am not able to identify the root cause since all the entries are in the same line and it is hard for me to g through with 300 items in just one line.

Comment: Well, you should not have to do that. The JSON format solves the quote issue for you. You should not have to "fix" your data, as quotes are in essence just as valid data as any other. But I am sure you also had another issue, related to UTF-8 encoding. We will probably never know.

Comment: I will post it for discussion some time if it happens. But Im good for now, at least.